DataGenerator Issues not working with 3D-Unet model (Brain Tumor Segmentation Task)
I'm working on brain tumor segmentation task using BRATS19 dataset. I'm getting an issue when trying to work with more than one epoch in fit method.
As per my analysis, on_epoch_end method of DataGenerator should be called internally to reset indices and provide valid indices for next epoch data generation. It shows AttributeError when next epoch starts and model crash, (AttributeError as next epoch starts with invalid indices). However, on_epoch_end should automatically clear indices.
# from scipy.ndimage import rotate, zoom, shift
# from numpy.random import randint, uniform
# from skimage.transform import resize
# from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler  # Class for scaling features to a range

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, batch_size=2, dim=(128,128,128), shuffle=True, channels=3, num_class=4, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # Call super constructor
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.channels = channels
        self.num_class = num_class
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return (len(self.list_IDs) // self.batch_size)


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        X = np.zeros((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.channels), dtype=np.float32)
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.num_class), dtype=np.float32)

        for i, img in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            t1_path, t2_path, t1ce_path, flair_path, mask_path = img

            image_t1 = nib.load(t1_path).get_fdata().astype(np.float32)
            image_t2 = nib.load(t2_path).get_fdata().astype(np.float32)
            image_t1ce = nib.load(t1ce_path).get_fdata().astype(np.float32)
            image_flair = nib.load(flair_path).get_fdata().astype(np.float32)

            x = np.stack([image_t1ce, image_t2, image_flair], axis=3)
            x = x[56:184, 56:184, 13:141]

            mask = nib.load(mask_path).get_fdata()
            mask = mask.astype(np.uint8)
            mask[mask == 4] = 3
            mask = keras.utils.to_categorical(mask, self.num_class)
            mask = mask[56:184, 56:184, 13:141]

            # Apply data augmentation with probability 10%
            if np.random.rand() < 0.10:
                x, mask = self.apply_augmentation(x, mask)

            # Resize to target dimensions
            x = resize(x, self.dim, anti_aliasing=True)
            mask = resize(mask, self.dim, anti_aliasing=False)

            # Normalize input data
            X[i] = x / 255.0
            y[i] = mask/255.0

        return X, y

    # Apply data augmentation to the image and mask
    def apply_augmentation(self, x, mask):

        # Randomly choose augmentation parameters
        angle = uniform(-10, 10)  # Rotation angle
        zoom_factor = uniform(0.95, 1.05)  # Zoom factor
        # Determine the dimensionality of the input array

        # Apply rotation to the image and mask
        x_augmented = rotate(x, angle, reshape=False, order=3)
        mask_augmented = rotate(mask, angle, reshape=False, order=0)

        # Apply zoom to the image and mask
        x_augmented = zoom(x_augmented, zoom_factor, order=3)
        mask_augmented = zoom(mask_augmented, zoom_factor, order=0)

        # Apply shift to the image and mask
        shift_factor = tuple(randint(-2.5, 2.5) for _ in range(x_augmented.ndim))
        x_augmented = shift(x_augmented, shift_factor, order=3)
        mask_augmented = shift(mask_augmented, shift_factor, order=0)

        # Resize augmented data to match original shape
        x_augmented = resize(x_augmented, x.shape[:-1], order=3, anti_aliasing=True)
        mask_augmented = resize(mask_augmented, mask.shape[:-1], order=0, anti_aliasing=False)

        return x_augmented, mask_augmented 

Training_datagen   = DataGenerator(Train, batch_size=2)
Validation_datagen = DataGenerator(Validation, batch_size=2)

# dice_loss and CustomMetrics() code not provided here
loss = dice_loss


metrics = [CustomMetrics()]

batch_size = 2
learning_rate = 0.0001
epochs = 30
optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_steps_per_epoch = len(Train)//batch_size
val_steps_per_epoch   = len(Validation)//batch_size

model = sm.Unet(backbone_name='vgg16', input_shape=(128, 128, 128, 3), classes=4, activation='softmax', encoder_weights='imagenet')

model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, TensorBoard, CSVLogger

# Define callbacks
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model_weights.keras', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=1e-6)
csv_logger = CSVLogger(filename='training.log')

history = model.fit(Training_datagen, epochs = 30, validation_data = Validation_datagen, verbose = 1,steps_per_epoch = train_steps_per_epoch, validation_steps = val_steps_per_epoch,callbacks = [checkpoint, early_stopping, reduce_lr, csv_logger])


I want it to be executed smoothly.
